# Difference between private static and private methods in a class

Tags: c++, static, tree, constants, private

I was going through a 'generictree' class designed by my instructor, and couldn't understand a concept.
There was a function in it which returned to the user, the node containing the highest value, below is its code.

```
const Node<T> * getLargestNode() const {
    return getLargestNodeHelper(root);

}
```

I understand that we require a helper function, because we need to do it recursively, and hence require an argument. Therefore, a helper function is required to pass the root as argument, because root cannot be passed as argument from main function, as access to internal data members is not required.
Below is the code for helper-function

```
private:
static const Node<T> * getLargestNodeHelper(const Node<T> * node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    const Node<T> * largest = node;
    for (int i = 0; i < node->children.size();i++) {
        const Node<T> * childlargest = getLargestNodeHelper(node->children[i]);
        if (childlargest->data > largest->data) {
            largest = childlargest;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Now, when I was trying to create same class on my own, I created  the helper function as shown below,

```
private:
 const Node<T> * getLargestNodeHelper(const Node<T> * node) const {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    const Node<T> * largest = node;
    for (int i = 0; i < node->children.size();i++) {
        const Node<T> * childlargest = getLargestNodeHelper(node->children[i]);
        if (childlargest->data > largest->data) {
            largest = childlargest;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Now, the doubt I am having is, is there any disadvantage on using my version of the helper-function. What is the difference between the two, as both cannot change the data members and both cannot be called from the object?

Answer (score 2):

If your method is not static, you need an object of that class to be able to call it (even if it doesn't care about the object you call it on). This comes - depending on situation - with the overhead of creating a dummy object and destroying it, just to use it once to call.
Static methods can be called without an object.

Comment: but since both are private, they can't be called from outside the class, right? So which one of the two is better practically?

Comment: @AkshatGupta Whichever makes sense semantically. If it's supposed to operate on an instance, don't make it `static`. NB You don't need an instance to call a non-static member unless it is virtual: you can do it by casting 0 to a pointer to the class.

Answer (score 0):

In your simple example there is no useful difference because getLargestNode() always requires an object. But in more complex class there could be other public but static member funcion that needs such helper function. In that case your function could not be called (code is not reused). One more thing is speed and memory (for very limited systems). Argument with pointer to object could take a place in the stack (in some systems). getLargestNodeHelper() is called recursively so more memory and more time. 
It's all about reusing of code. And don't give to a recursive function more than it requires.